# Get a css property in javascript on page load

Tags: javascript, css

I m trying to get a css property on page load but as you can see below, it never shows the display but it shows correctly if I change it. My question is how can I display the "block" on **Display 1**?

Thanks for your help

```js
let hello = document.getElementById('hello');

document.getElementById('you').innerHTML += hello.style.display;

hello.style.display = "inline-block";

document.getElementById('too').innerHTML += hello.style.display
```

```css
#hello {
  background-color:yellow;
  height:20px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="hello">Hello</div>
<div id="you">Display 1: </div>
<div id="too">Display 2: </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.style` reads from the inline styles of an element (as in `<div style="...">`), not the stylesheet. You can use `hello.getBoundingClientRect().height` to read the height of a DOM element.

Alternatively, you could use `getComputedStyle`:

```js
const styles = window.getComputedStyle(hello)
const height = styles.getPropertyValue('height')
```

Comment: I needed to get the display value and your getBoundingClientRect() doesn't work for it so I edited my post

The getComputedStyle is what I needed, thanks :)